# Masonry – 2xwidth in first element

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-masonry

http://ericulous.com/ipin/

Why I can add bigger width to every post except first?

> [image: first post]

[image: other post]

Comment: You have to show the code you're using.

Comment: This is free theme, I change only width: http://ericulous.com/2012/09/21/wp-theme-ipin-pinterest-clone/
Masonry.js: http://ericulous.com/ipin/wp-content/themes/ipin/js/jquery.masonry.min.js

Answer (score 0):

In function.php find

```
$masonry.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $masonry.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.thumb',
            isFitWidth: true,
            }).css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('#ajax-loader-masonry').hide();
        });
```

and replace

```
$masonry.imagesLoaded( function(){
            $masonry.masonry({
                itemSelector : '.thumb',
                isFitWidth: true,
                columnWidth: 10
            }).css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('#ajax-loader-masonry').hide();
        });
```